# jquery mobile windows phone 7 multipage not working

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

In the windows phone emulator simple jquery mobile multi-page navigation does not work.
Does anyone have a solution?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-      
scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.1.0.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/phonegap-1.3.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jq.mob-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/data.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/knockout.js"></script>         
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {

    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Home Page -->
<div data-role="page" id="home" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Menu</h2>
        <a href="#page1">page 1</a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Home Page End -->
<!-- Page 1 -->
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Page 1</h2>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Page 1 End -->
</body>
```

Edit: I have added the head section for more clarity.

I think multi-page navigation must be broken for Windows phone so if anyone knows an alternative I would be grateful

Comment: Please post the complete code for your page. What you have appears to be correct but what about the `<head>`?

Answer (score 0):

you can use your own function to show and hide div by using the display attribute and using document.getElementById('')